# SharePoint 2013: Custom Display Form - "Unable to display this Web Part" when

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, custom-form

### My Questions

**Question 1:** Has anyone seen Error below when working with 20+ lookup fields in custom Display form?
**Question 2:** Can it be fixed/ worked around/ hacked/ etc...?

### Error: *Unable to display this Web Part*

**Default DispForm.aspx:** I have checked this with running default *"DispForm.aspx"* and runs fine.
**DispForm_Custom.aspx:**  However, When I create a *DispForm_Custom.aspx* and try to run form in browser, not making a single edit, it returns *Unable to display this Web Part*. This List has 25 Lookup Columns. I can add 19 lookup fields but not 20.
**Lookup Column List:** Unit1 - Unit25 = **UnitSupportList** where it returns the title from that list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [SharePoint 2013 - *Software boundaries and limits*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt493258(v=office.16).aspx)

***Applies to:*** SharePoint 2013, SharePoint Foundation 2013, SharePoint Server 2013

### Throttling and limits

Limits prevent operations that adversely affect farm performance. These defaults have been tested and carefully chosen. For some limits, such as the list view threshold, Microsoft strongly recommend not changing the value(s). Again, they strongly urge you to carefully consider the effect of changing these limits. As such, if these limits prevent an operation from being performed, first consider changing the operation to run in a more efficiently indexed way rather than changing the limit to accommodate poorly performing operations [(read more...)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813.aspx#Throttling)

### List view lookup threshold

1. **Maximum value**

   - 12 join operations per query
2. **Limit Type**

   - Threshold
3. **Notes**

   - Specifies the maximum number of joins allowed per query, such as those based on lookup, person/group, or workflow status columns. If the query uses more than eight joins, the operation is blocked. This does not apply to single item operations. When using the maximal view via the object model (by not specifying any view fields), SharePoint will return up to the first 12 lookups.
   - Note: After applying the SharePoint Server 2013 cumulative update package released on August 13, 2013 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2817616), the default value is increased from 8 to 12. [(read more...)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt493258(v=office.16).aspx#ListLibrary)

### References

1. [SharePoint 2013 - *Software boundaries and limits*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt493258(v=office.16).aspx)
2. [Microsoft TechNet: Designing large lists and maximizing list performance](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262813.aspx#Throttling)

Answer (score 0):

You could increase the value of the List View Lookup Threshold in central administration.

Go to central administration->manage web applications->select one web application->click general settings in the ribbon->select Resource Throttling->increase the value of the List View Lookup Threshold and save changes.

And you also could split the list to several lists to store the data.

Comment: I thought about that [Amy_SPWX](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/35665/amy-spwx) but then that would possibly degrade the integrity of the Server. I decided against that ultimately. As the list grows this could be exponentially problematic and would eventually cascade data failures.